# Implement an EGARCH model with the Student-$t$ distribution in rugarch

Tags: r, garch

I am trying to estimate an EAGRCH model with a Student-$t$ distribution using the `rugarch` package. However, when I show the output it says that the conditional variance dynamics assumes a normal distribution instead of a Student-$t$ distribution. My code is shown below:

```r
EXT <- matrix(cbind(COVID1, COVID2), ncol = 2)
spec1 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "eGARCH",
                                         garchOrder = c(1, 1),
                                         submodel = NULL,
                                         external.regressors = NULL,
                                         variance.targeting = FALSE),

                   mean.model     = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1),
                                         external.regressors = NULL,
                                         distribution.model = "std",
                                         start.pars = list(),
                                         fixed.pars = list()))

DJI_garch <- ugarchfit(spec = spec1, data = DJI, solver.control = list(trace=0))
```

How do you implement an Student-$t$ distribution in the variance dynamics? Did I wrongly implement the `distribution.model`? see image below.

[image]

Comment: Exactly, therefore the default was norm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to close a parenthesis before `distribution.model = "std"` as the latter is not part of `mean.model`. See the [help file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rugarch/versions/1.4-4/topics/ugarchspec-methods) of the function `ugarchspec` for details.